# Example highlighting overprotection

Tags: strategy, positional-play

Nimzovich was a proponent of the idea of over-protection, a concept which I don't understand well enough to ever implement in my games. Are there any example games at the GM level that illustrate this concept particularly well as a theme?

Comment: Well there's this contrived example of Nimzovich's: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1334664

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Nimzovich did not actually play that game. That was made up as a joke to make fun of overprotection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic game that is typically used to explain 'excessive' protection is Aron Nimzowitsch vs A Giese (played in 1913)

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1316457

pay attention to moves 10. Nf3! (first defense of e5) then 11. Re1! (second defense), and finally 13. Bf4! (third defense of e5)